# How to solve error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find main: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to create a `makefile` to run a simple C++ application in VS code, but I am getting a Linker error when it tries to execute the target to create the executable file:

```bash
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 2 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:5: main] Error 1
```

I searched for posts related to the `/usr/bin/ld:` message, but they all seemed to be linked to problems having to with connecting to external shared library files.

M application, on the other hand, uses **no external libraries** but instead keeps all of the files, including the object(`.o`) files and final executable, in **the same directory**.

Here is the makefile code:

```
CXX = g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

main: main.o Movies.o Movie.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $@ $^

main.o: main.cpp Movies.cpp Movie.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

Movie.o: Movie.cpp Movie.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

Movies.o: Movies.cpp Movies.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

run:
    ./main

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

UPDATE: I should add that I am fairly new to C++ and makefiles in general. My original intent was to build up the makefile by creating the individual targets for each of my source files as a means of practicing and learning.

The `Movies.cpp` class is nothing more than a container class to hold a collection of `Movie.cpp` objects, more specifically a vector for `Movie` objects. The actual `main.cpp` file only includes the `Movies.h` header in its `main()` function.

I hope this extra information helps.

Comment: Please include in your example the command that was invoked that generated those error messages (it will be printed out by make), not just the error messages themselves.

Comment: However, the problem is probably that your link line should be `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^` (note the `-o` which you are missing from your command line)

Comment: g++  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main main.o Movies.o Movie.o

Comment: `main.o: main.cpp Movies.cpp Movie.cpp` does not look right to me. Should be one object file built from one source file.

Comment: If you would build your program manually, by entering the commands yourself one by one, how would they look like? Do your makefile replicate those commands *exactly*?

Comment: Oh, and having `Movies.cpp` *and* `Movie.cpp`? That will surely confuse most readers.

Comment: Your compiler recipes should be using `$<` not `$^` since you only want to pass the source file to the compiler, not all the prerequisites.

Comment: I have tried running `main.o: main.cpp` but I get an error of `undefined reference to ` to methods from the `Movies.cpp` file as `main.cpp` relies on those to run.

Comment: And while writing your explicit rules and commands for every file might be good to learn, once you've done that a few times I recommend you learn about *implicit rules*. All you really need is `main: main.o Movies.o Movie.o` as the single rule in your makefile. The `make` program will then be able to figure almost everything else out by itself.

Comment: What is your `main.o` *really* building? Is it building an object file, or an executable file? What should it build? As I said above, do your makefile *exactly* replicate the commands you type yourself?

Comment: If I only include the following target ```main: main.o Movies.o Movie.o
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $@ $^``` then the error narrows down to ```/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:5: main] Error 1```

Comment: You still haven't fixed the issue in my second comment: you're missing a `-o` on the link line.  That's why you're getting this error.  All the other things are just "other issues".

Comment: See e.g. [this makefile](https://gist.github.com/pileon/da35f0f64322ad382f1265fb48654790) fow how to make it simpler. This also includes (automatically) a fix to the problem you have. From this just do `make run` to automatically build all object files, link them into the `main` executable program, and then run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main.o` rule command `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^` w/o `-c` does not build an object file, it builds `./main.o` executable. Compare it with other rules. `main` rule command links with `main.o` executable and the command fails.

This is all what you need

```make
CXX = g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

main: main.cpp Movies.cpp Movie.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

run: main
    ./main

clean:
    rm -f main
```

Or fix the rule `main.o` and command sources

```make
XX = g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

main: main.o Movies.o Movie.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $@ $^

main.o: main.cpp Movie.h Movies.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Movie.o: Movie.cpp Movie.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Movies.o: Movies.cpp Movies.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

run: main
    ./main

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

Comment: (The first one works because `make` automatically knows how to build cpp files into o files, so you don't have to tell it, unless you want to customize it)

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up, I appreciate it. The program now runs as intended.